# XSD schema returns empty list instead of null value?

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, xsd

I have a webservice soap service that takes an object with an optional list as xml parameter:

```
<xs:complexType name="objectType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Sleutel1" type="StringMax128Type" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:simpleType name="StringMax128Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>String with max 128 characters</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="128"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I would expect the following results with theses scenario's:

SCENARIO 1: the request contains no tag.
Result: sleutel1 = null

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <upd:Update version="1.0">
     <Info>
     </Info>
  </upd:Update>
</soapenv:Body>
```

SCENARIO 2: the request contains an empty tag.
Result: sleutel1 = empty list

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <upd:Update version="1.0">
     <Info>
       <Sleutel1></Sleutel1>
     </Info>
  </upd:Update>
</soapenv:Body>
```

SCENARIO 3: the request contains a filled tag.
Result: sleutel1 = filled list

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <upd:Update version="1.0">
     <Info>
       <Sleutel1>A</Sleutel1>
       <Sleutel1>B</Sleutel1>
       <Sleutel1>C</Sleutel1>
     </Info>
  </upd:Update>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But for some reason it always wants to return an empty arraylist instead of null? Is it possible to remove this rule to always return a new arraylist? My service updates an object and I would like to have a null value so that i can see the difference between a request that doesn't want to update this specific value or a request that wants to remove or add to the value.

The code below is genererated from the schema.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Sleutel1", nillable = true)
protected List<String> sleutel1;

/**
 * Gets the value of the sleutel1 property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the sleutel1 property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getSleutel1().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link String }
 * 
 * 
 */

public List<String> getSleutel1() {
    if (sleutel1 == null) {
        sleutel1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return this.sleutel1;
}
```

Comment: There does not appear to be a question here. You have identified the code that is generated and it is simple and clearly never returns a null value for the list. Semantically, no tag and empty tag are equivalent. To simplify life for anyone using the generated code, a null value is never returned - instead a list that represents all the values that were present in the document is returned.

Comment: Please edit your question and show examples of XML content which would fit Scenario 1 and Scenario 2.  I’m pretty sure that the absence of any `Sleutel1` children in the XML represents a List with length zero, every time.

Comment: My question would be: Is it possible to remove this rule to always return a new arraylist? My service updates an object and I would like to have a null value so that i can see the difference between a request that doesn't want to update this specific value or a request that wants to remove or add to the value.

Comment: Is the lack of elements in the list i.e. zero elements not a indication  like NULl.

Comment: In an update scenario. how would i know the difference between someone who doesn't want to update the list versus someone who wants to set the list empty? If the first person doesn't want to update the list but the result is an empty list anyway then how can i notice the difference? I can use an extra type as middleman and let that object be null, but I wanted to know if there is any kind of configuration or methods to overcome this.

Comment: The xml for a null could look something like this:
`<soapenv:Body>
  <upd:Update version="1.0">
     <Info>
       <Sleutel1 nil=xsi:nil="true"></Sleutel1>
     </Info>
  </upd:Update>
</soapenv:Body>`
And in such a case the implementation could return null instead of empty list to describe the difference.